# Visual Studio 2019 Merge changed with unmodified

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2019, merge-conflict-resolution

Working in visual studio & GIT, I have a helpful tool that generates classes, appservices, and related files for domain driven design project.

This is a huge time saver, except when I need to modify an entity.

When I use the tool, I commit my changes, run the tool, then go through every modified file and copy over my changes manually in Diff.

How could I use merge instead, in that circumstance?

If I right click a file, I have Compare with unmodified.

Is there a way to add "Merge with unmodified"?

Or - is there a way to take both branches and trigger git to consider all changed files conflicted, so visual studio presents me with Merge option?